# How to use BeauifulSoup for parsing data in following example?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python and BeautifulSoup and I am trying to make a web scraper. However, I am facing some issues and can't figure out a way out. Here is my issue:

This is part of the HTML from where I want to scrap:

```
<tr>
    <td class="num cell-icon-string" data-sort-value="6">
    <td class="cell-icon-string"><a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/charizard" title="View pokedex for #006 Charizard">Charizard</a></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="num cell-icon-string" data-sort-value="6">
    <td class="cell-icon-string"><a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/charizard" title="View pokedex for #006 Charizard">Charizard</a><br>
    <small class="aside">Mega Charizard X</small></td>
</tr>
```

Now, I want to extract "Charizard" from 1st table row and "Mega Charizard X" from the second row. Right now, I am able to extract "Charizard" from both rows.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("data.html"), "lxml")
poke_boxes = soup.findAll('a', attrs = {'class': 'ent-name'})

for poke_box in poke_boxes:
    poke_name = poke_box.text.strip()
        print(poke_name)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to change your logic to go through the rows and check to see if the small element exists, if it does print out that text, otherwise print out the anchor text as you are now.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
trs = soup.findAll('tr')
for tr in trs:
    smalls = tr.findAll('small')
    if smalls:
        print(smalls[0].text)
    else:
        poke_box = tr.findAll('a')
        print(poke_box[0].text)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I understood your logic and with a few workarounds, was able to implement the required thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4
html = '''<tr>
    <td class="num cell-icon-string" data-sort-value="6">
    <td class="cell-icon-string"><a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/charizard" title="View pokedex for #006 Charizard">Charizard</a></td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="num cell-icon-string" data-sort-value="6">
    <td class="cell-icon-string"><a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/charizard" title="View pokedex for #006 Charizard">Charizard</a><br>
    <small class="aside">Mega Charizard X</small></td>
</tr>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

in:

```
[tr.get_text(strip=True) for tr in soup('tr')]
```

out:

```
['Charizard', 'CharizardMega Charizard X']
```

you can use `get_text()` to concatenate all the text in the tag, `strip=Ture` will strip all the space in the string